# How do I separate words using regex in python while considering words with apostrophes?

Tags: python, regex

I tried separate m's in a python regex by using word boundaries and find them all. These m's should either have a whitespace on both sides or begin/end the string:

```
r = re.compile("\\bm\\b")
re.findall(r, someString)
```

However, this method also finds m's within words like `I'm` since apostrophes are considered to be word boundaries. How do I write a regex that doesn't consider apostrophes as word boundaries?

I've tried this:

```
r = re.compile("(\\sm\\s) | (^m) | (m$)")
re.findall(r, someString)
```

but that just doesn't match any m. Odd.

Comment: The reason your `\\s` example doesn't match any `m` is because of the extra space around the pipes. Those are included in the search string. Otherwise, that works for me without lookaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lookaround assertion:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)m(?=\s)|^m|m$', "I'm a boy")
[]
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)m(?=\s)|^m|m$', "I m a boy")
['m']
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)m(?=\s)|^m|m$', "mama")
['m']
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)m(?=\s)|^m|m$', "pm")
['m']
```

> `(?=...)`
>
> Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the
>   string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac
>   `(?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.
>
> `(?<=...)`
>
> Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match
>   for `...` that ends at the current position. This is called a positive
>   lookbehind assertion. `(?<=abc)def` will find a match in `abcdef`, ...
>
> from [Regular expression syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

BTW, using raw string (`r'this is raw string'`), you don't need to escape `\`.

```
>>> r'\s' == '\\s'
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need look-around (unless you want to capture the m without the spaces), but your second example was inches away. It was the extra spaces (ok in python, but not within a regex) which made them not work:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\sm\s|^m|m$', "I m a boy")
[' m ']
>>> re.findall(r'\sm\s|^m|m$', "mamam")
['m', 'm']
>>> re.findall(r'\sm\s|^m|m$', "mama")
['m']
>>> re.findall(r'\sm\s|^m|m$', "I'm a boy")
[]
>>> re.findall(r'\sm\s|^m|m$', "I'm a boym")
['m']
```

Comment: Or use [`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.X) and you can leave the spaces in. This is often useful for complicated regexps--and for a novice, almost any regexp can be complicated.

Answer (score 1):

falsetru's answer is *almost* the equivalent of "\b except apostrophes", but not quite.  It will still find matches where a boundary is missing.  Using one of falsetru's examples:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)m(?=\s)|^m|m$', "mama")
['m']
```

It finds 'm', but there is no occurrence of 'm' in 'mama' that would match '\bm\b'.  The first 'm' matches '\bm', but that's as close as it gets.

The regex that implements "\b without apostrophes" is shown below:

```
(?<=\s)m(?=\s)|^m(?=\s)|(?<=\s)m$|^m$
```

This will find any of the following 4 cases:

1. 'm' with white space before and after
2. 'm' at beginning followed by white space
3. 'm' at end preceded by white space
4. 'm' with nothing preceding or following it (i.e. just literally the string "m")