# Extract surrounding words in python from a string position

Tags: python, regex, string, search

Let's assume, I have a string:

```
string="""<p>It is common for content in Arabic, Hebrew, and other languages that use right-to-left scripts to include numerals or include text from  other scripts. Both of these typically flow  left-to-right within the overall right-to-left  context. </p> <p>This article tells you how to write HTML where text with different writing directions is mixed <em>within a paragraph or other HTML block</em> (ie. <dfn id="term_inline">inline or phrasal</dfn> content). (A companion article <a href="/International/questions/qa-html-dir"><cite>Structural markup and right-to-left text in HTML</cite></a> tells you how to use HTML markup for  elements such as <code class="kw">html</code>, and structural markup such as <code class="kw">p</code> or <code class="kw">div</code> and forms.)</p>"""
```

and I have a position of word in this string, for example:

```
>>> pos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("tells you", string)]
>>> pos
[263, 588]
```

I need to extract several words behind and several words after from each position.
How to implement it using Python and regular expressions?

E.g.:

```
def look_through(d, s):
    r = []
    content = readFile(d["path"])
    content = BeautifulSoup(content)
    content = content.getText()
    pos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(s, content)]
    if pos:
        if "phrase" not in d:
            d["phrase"] = [s]
        else:
            d["phrase"].append(s)
        for p in pos:
            r.append({"content": content, "phrase": d["phrase"], "name": d["name"]})
    for b in d["decendent"] or []:
            r += look_through(b, s)
    return r

>>> dict = {
    "content": """<p>It is common for content in Arabic, Hebrew, and other languages that use right-to-left scripts to include numerals or include text from  other scripts. Both of these typically flow  left-to-right within the overall right-to-left  context. </p>""", 
    "name": "directory", 
    "decendent": [
         {
            "content": """<p>This article tells you how to write HTML where text with different writing directions is mixed <em>within a paragraph or other HTML block</em> (ie. <dfn id="term_inline">inline or phrasal</dfn> content). (A companion article <a href="/International/questions/qa-html-dir"><cite>Structural markup and right-to-left text in HTML</cite></a> tells you how to use HTML markup for  elements such as <code class="kw">html</code>, and structural markup such as <code class="kw">p</code> or <code class="kw">div</code> and forms.)</p>""", 
            "name": "subdirectory", 
            "decendent": None
        }, 
        {
            "content": """It tells you how to use HTML markup for  elements such as <code class="kw">html</code>, and structural markup such as <code class="kw">p</code> or <code class="kw">div</code> and forms.)""", 
            "name": "subdirectory_two", 
            "decendent": [
                {
                    "content": "Name 4", 
                    "name": "subsubdirectory", 
                    "decendent": None
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So:

```
>>> look_through(dict, "tells you")
[
    { "content": "This article tells you how to", "phrase": "tells you", "name": "subdirectory" },
    { "content": "It tells you how to use", "phrase": "tells you", "name": "subdirectory_two" }
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a small example to your question?

Comment: Have you tried writing this code? You're likely to get a better response when we can see what you have already tried or how you are thinking about solving the problem.

Comment: Still its unclear that how you get `"This article tells you how to"`

Comment: I think @Kasra and I are both curious what you have tried for the implementation of `look_through`.

Comment: @amccormack, I added an example how I get the position of a text. Now I'd like to extract the part of a text from content where exatcly it was found. And I see two solutions here: using position or using the regular expression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338125/how-i-display-2-words-before-and-after-a-key-search-word-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You want a "concordance" of your regexp hits, let's say two words before and after the place where your regexps matched. The easiest way to do it is to **break your string there and anchor your search to the endpoints of the pieces**. For example, to get two words before and after index 263 (your first `m.start()`), you'd do:

```
m_left = re.search(r"(?:\s+\S+){,2}\s+\S*$", text[:263])
m_right = re.search(r"^\S*\s+(?:\S+\s+){2,}", text[263:])
print(text[m_left.start():m_right.end()])
```

The first expression should be read from the end of the string backwards: It anchors at the end `$`, possibly skips a partial word if the match ended mid-word, (`\S*`), skips some spaces (`\s+`), and then matches *up to two* `{2,}` word-space sequences, `\s+\S+`. It's not *exactly* two because if we reach the beginning of the string, we want to return a short match.

The second regexp does the same but in reverse direction.

For a concordance you'd probably want to start reading right after the *end* of the regexp match, not the beginning. In that case, use `m.end()` as the beginning of the second string.

It's pretty obvious how to use this with a list of regexp matches, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I first proposed using word boundary meta characters, but that's not quite right, because they don't consume any of the string, and \B doesn't really match what I wanted it to anyway.

Instead, I propose using the underlying definition of a word boundary -- that is, the boundary between \W and \w. Look for one or more word character (\w) along with one or more non-word character (\W) in the right order, repeated  as many times as you want, on either side of the search substring.

For example:
`(?:\w+\W+){,3}some string(?:\W+\w+){,3}`

This finds up to three words before and up to three words after "some string".

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19331391/228489) for how to deal with words that contain apostrophes like "Don't" or "Haven't".

Comment: Boundaries don't take up space. `\b\B` matches a point that is a word boundary and is not a word boundary, so it will never match anywhere.

Comment: @alexis, yes, that's why I continued on in my answer.

Comment: And take into acount the case, when symbols are not english (in my case they are Cyrillic).

Comment: @paus, you can use the UNICODE or LOCALE flags to modify the definition of \w and \W. Check the docs:https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html